# Magento2 - After I changed my dns my admin url throws a 404

Tags: magento2

I developed a site with a generic system url through my hosting company. When I switched my dns to the sites regular domain name my admin are throws a 404 error now.

Comment: Did you change base_url, base_secure_url in the core_config_data table?

Comment: Bse Secure isn't in the table. Do you know if I can add it manually that it will work?